# How to change a particular row value Day 1, Day 2...etc, to be a column value of the same Row in R programming

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

How to change a particular row value Day 1, Day 2...etc, to be a column value of the same Row in R programming and it should remove the entire row where we had Day 15(example)

**Data:**

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- structure(list(GID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "NG1", "MG2", "MG3", "NG4"), 
                      ColA = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                      ColB = c("2", "4", "4", "Day 15", "5", "N", "1", "1", "N")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -9L), 
                 class = "data.frame")
```

**Code:**

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~replace(., . == '', 'N')), 
         GID = sub('N', '', GID)) %>%
  select(-where(~all(is.na(.)))) %>%
  rename_with(~names(df1)[seq_along(.)])
```

**output:**

```
#  GID   ColA
#1   1    2
#2   2    4
#3   3    4
#4   4   DAY 15
#5   5    5
#6  G1    N
#7 MG2    1
#8 MG3    1
#9  G4    N
```

**Expected Output:**

```
#  GID   Day 15
#1        4
#2   2    4
#3   3    4
#4   4    Day 15
#5   5    5
#6  G1    N
#7 MG2    1
#8 MG3    1
#9  G4    N
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do here, like for example why you'd have ColA in there at all if it's just got a load of NA values. I suspect that there's something upstream of your stated problem which might be the better place to fix this, but here's a solution regardless:

Assuming that "Day 15" is a specific example of a more general value type that you're trying to find, `str_detect(ColB, "[a-z]+")` will detect lower case characteres, so it will find the `a` and the `y` of `Day`, and I'm filtering on that. If there's only ever one of those in ColB we can save that value to the column name: Assigning that to the thrid column's name:

```
library(tidyverse)
names(df1)[3] <- df1 %>% filter(str_detect(ColB, "[a-z]+")) %>% select(ColB) %>% as.character()
```

And then filtering that same string out of the data:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% filter(!str_detect(get(names(df1)[3]), names(df1)[3]))
```

And then removing ColA to get your desired output:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% select(-ColA)
```

I have the `1` in row 1 of `GID`, but I assume you removing that was a mistake? Also, in your first paragraph you've stated that you'd like to remove the value "Day 15", but you've put it in your "expected output"; just don't run the second filter if you want that to stay.